# What does "super-integrable" mean?

Tags: integration, terminology, symmetry

What does "super-integrable" mean?

Example from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09612) (p. 2):

> …the
>   Coulomb problem is super-integrable. Namely, it is not just rotation invariant,
>   but as well admits further integrals given by the Runge-Lenz vector.

Does it mean the differential equation has multiple symmetries and can thus be integrated more than one way?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintegrable_Hamiltonian_system). If you like slides, then [this one](http://gemma.ujf.cas.cz/~krejcirik/AAMP13/slides/Winternitz.pdf) is good, about Superintegrability.

Comment: Considering that the tag (differential-equations) has been removed [relatively recently](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/tag-management-2018/28599#comment126373_28599), I think that a better option would be to choose one of the more specific tags - ([tag:ode]) or ([tag:pde]). (Or both, if they are applicable to the question.)